# Custom JWT when RequestPasswordTokenAsync in IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, identityserver4

I want add some information on `tokenResponse.AccessToken`(PhoneNumber, Address,...) when use RequestPasswordTokenAsync.
Is there any way to do that?

```
    var tokenResponse = await client.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(new PasswordTokenRequest
                {
                    Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,
                    ClientId = "ro.client.30",
                    ClientSecret = "secret",

                    UserName = "aaa",
                    Password = "bbb",
                    Scope = "api1",

                });
```

Comment: It depends more on how your IdentityServer instance is configured to run I reckon? Try asking for the `openid` scope and see what's being returned.

Comment: Sorry I don't know where configuration of openid. Do we have document for it?

Comment: Docs are at http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/ No offense, but if that is part your question, I recommend taking a fair bit of time to read the tutorials there before continuing. This stuff's complex and can become frustrating quite quickly otherwise.

Comment: I read this document, but I didn't see any information about custom data in token.
The openid or profile has only some default fields what I need. I want have more fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using InMemory ApiResources, change you Config in this way :

```
        var api1 = new ApiResource("api1", "My API");

        api1.UserClaims.Add("PhoneNumber");
        new List<ApiResource>
        {
            api1
        };
```

when someone request for a token which contains api1 scope, specefied UserClaims in api1's ApiResource will be added to it's token

Comment: The `PhoneNumber` is field name of `IdentityUser`, right? If I have `Code` field in `IdentityUser` class then do the same, right? But I want set any fields from other class then I can't.

Comment: I found a solution for my problem, I would handle in `ProfileService`

Comment: are this information about user? i mean the information you wana put in token. if yes, you can implement IProfileService and add anything you want into token.

Comment: if you wana your profile information in token, you should set client property. AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true